# Is there a way to alias "require" paths with React Native's packager?

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a way to alias paths with React Native so instead of something like:

```
require('../../blah')
```

I could do:

```
require('src/blah')
```

where 'src' is at the root of the directory.

Comment: I couldn't find a definitive answer to this using just react-packager, now I use webpack to compile all of my own source files and react-packager to do the few special-er things that are required for react-native. Essentially, react-packager packages one file that has a require('webpack_bundle.js'). I can go into this further if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the name of your application as "root". (the name that is written in your `package.json`):

```js
require('<package name>/img/yourimage.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the fbjs @providesModule pragma. Basically by prepending your sourcefile with:

```
/**
 * @providesModule blah
 */
```

it enables you to `require('blah')` in other files.

AFAIK this functionality is supposed to be for Facebook use only so it might cause warnings or break in the future.

Comment: Thanks @oblador. I haven't had a chance to test yet, but will update when I do.

Comment: This is one small step in the right direction but what about aliasing to arbitrary paths on disk instead of within the project folder?

Comment: @Qiming: Try `npm link` or just regular `ln -s`, however packager doesn't support this just yet.

Comment: Yeah please don't use this @providesModule.

Answer (score 0):

+1 I also need this feature.

Right now I'm using browserify to bundle my js files marking react-native as external, and use the aliasify module for path aliases. As a second step I pass my bundle to the packager.

The only other solution I've found so far is having your modules in the node_modules directory (maybe with links).

Both of these solutions seem hacky and uncomfortable to me...